# Implement find/find next algorithm

Tags: sql, database, postgresql

I have a database table (mysql/pgsql) with the following format:

```
id|text
 1| the cat is black
 2| a cat is a cat
 3| a dog
```

I need to select the line that contains nth match of a word:

eg: "Select the 3rd match for the word cat, that is the number 2 entry."
Results: the 2nd row from the result where the 3rd word is cat

The only solution I could find is to search for all entries that have the text cat, load them in memory and find the match by counting them. But this is not efficient for a big number of matches(>1 million).

How would you handle this in an efficient way? Is there anything you can do directly in the database? Maybe using other technologies like lucene?

Update: having 1 million strings in memory might not be a big issue but the expectation of the application is to have between 1k-50k active users that might do this operation concurrently.

Comment: This sounds more like a programming problem than a database problem.  I'm not 100% sure but I think the solution you mentioned it the only way, though I'm not sure why you would want to do this in a database.

Comment: Did you have a look into the full text search capabilities of Postgres? Are the words always separated by spaces? Do you need to do partial matches? (e.g. user searches for `cat` but that should also return and line with `cats`). What exactly do you mean with "*number 2 entry*"? The row with the `id = 2` or the "second row in the result based on the order of the `id` column"?

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name I don't need partial matches for the moment and we can use space as a separator. Can you provide a simple example in psql?

Comment: I don't get the example still. None of the examples have third word of cat.

Comment: @danip: please, check my answer.

Comment: Am I right in thinking the solution would need to be flexible for searching for any word (i.e. from an infinite list) or might there be a finite list of possible search words that would be known up front? Also when you say "space as a separator", would other characters need to be considered such as `cat, `, `cat. `, `cat;`, `cat)`,`cat"` etc. or is it OK to assume such characters are not present?

Comment: What about using a cache if your data doesn't change often ?

Comment: @danip, if I was trying to find the nth instance of 'rat', would the words 'rats' and 'krats' increment that count?

Comment: @danip, add or modify your DB tables to improve efficiency or is it fixed?

Comment: When you say "word" you mean a constant string delimited by space characters or start / end of string, right? No flexing like in natural languages (cat / cats). Case sensitive.

Comment: There's nothing that defines the order that ID 1 is before ID 2.  Finding the "3rd" occurrence could equally return 1 as valid because record 2 has 2 occurrences and record 1 would supply the 3rd.  So without defining the order of how you are linearly searching this question cannot be answered.  Using a tech like lucene would result in the same problem of defining the linear nature of records.

Answer (score 11):

Consider creating another table with the below structure

```
Table : index_table
columns : 
         index_id , word, occurrence, id(foreign key to your original table)
```

Do one time indexing process as below:

Iterate over each entry in your original table split the text into words and for each word lookup in the new table for existence if not present insert a new entry with occurrence set as 1. If exists insert a new entry with occurrence = existing occurrence +1

Once you have done this one off indexing your selects become pretty simple. 
For example for cat with 3rd match will be

```
SELECT * 
FROM original_table o, index_table idx
WHERE idx.word = 'cat' 
  AND idx.occurrence = 3 
  AND o.id = idx.id
```

Comment: In your query you can use `INNER JOIN` ;).

Answer (score 4):

You do not need Lucene for this job. Furthermore, if you have a large number of positive matches, the effort to pump all required data out of your DB will well exceed the computational cost.

Here's a simple solution:

**Index**: we require two properties:

1. efficiently access the words for each id
2. efficiently access all IDs in ascending order

as follows:

```
create index i_words on example_data (id, string_to_array(txt, ' '));
```

**Query**: find the ID associated with the `n`th match with the following query:

```
select id
from (
    select id, unnest(string_to_array(txt, ' ')) as word
    from example_data
) words
where word = :w     -- :w = 'cat'
offset :n - 1       -- :n = 3
limit 1;
```

Executes in **2ms** on 1 million rows.

---

Here's the full PostgreSQL setup if you'd rather try for yourself than take my word for it:

```
drop table if exists example_data;
create table example_data (
    id integer primary key,
    txt text not null
);

insert into example_data
(select generate_series(1, 1000000, 3) as id, 'the cat is black' as txt
union all
select generate_series(2, 1000000, 3), 'a cat is a cat'
union all
select generate_series(3, 1000000, 3), 'a dog'
order by id);

commit;

drop index if exists i_words;
create index i_words on example_data (id, string_to_array(txt, ' '));

select id
from (
    select id, unnest(string_to_array(txt, ' ')) as word
    from example_data
) words
where word = 'cat'
offset 3 - 1
limit 1;

select 
    id, word
from (
    select id, unnest(string_to_array(txt, ' ')) as word
    from example_data
) words
where word = 'cat'
offset 3 - 1
limit 1;
```

Answer (score 2):

Note that I'm still unsure what exactly "*Select the 3rd match for the word cat, that is the number 2 entry*" is supposed to mean.

Possible meanings:

1. the 2nd row from the result where the 3rd word is cat
2. the 3rd row where the 2nd word is "cat"
3. from all rows where "cat" appears at least 3 times, take the second row
4. from all rows where "cat" appears at least 2 times, take the third row

---

If it's 1 or 2, I think this could be done in an acceptable speed by using a trigram index to reduce the possible number of matching lines. A trigram index (supplied by the [module pg_trgm](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/pgtrgm.html)) will allow Postgres to make use of an index when doing a e.g. `like '%cat%'`.

Assuming that only a small number of rows will satisfy that condition, the resulting lines can then be split into arrays and checked for the nth word.

Something like this:

```
with matching_rows as (
  select id, line, 
         row_number() over (order by id) as rn
  from the_table
  where line like '%cat%' -- this hopefully reduces the result to only very few rows
)
select *
from matching_rows 
where rn = 3 --<< "the third match for the word cat"
  and (string_to_array(line, ' '))[2] = 'cat' -- "the second word is "cat"
```

Note that a trigram index *does* have disadvantages as well. Maintaining such an index is much more expensive (=slower) than maintaining a regular b-tree index. So if your table is heavily updated, this might not be a good solution - but you need to test that for yourself.

Also if the condition `like '%cat%' doesn't really reduce the number of rows substantially, this is probably not going to perform well either.

Some more information on trigram indexes:

- http://www.depesz.com/index.php/2011/02/19/waiting-for-9-1-faster-likeilike/
- http://www.postgresonline.com/journal/archives/212-PostgreSQL-9.1-Trigrams-teaching-LIKE-and-ILIKE-new-tricks.html

Another option would be to filter out the "relevant" rows using Postgres' full text search instead of a plain `LIKE` condition.

Comment: The meanings is : the 2nd row from the result where the 3rd word is cat  (i've updated the question)

Comment: I think the answer is correct but way more complex then I would have hopped :). I expect to have a lot of matches so I'm not sure how well this will work. Can you elaborate a bit about your last remark: "filter out the relevant results" using full text search?

Comment: @danip: I just meant you might want to test if using Postgres' full text search gives you a better performance that a trigram index with `like`. Not sure what you mean with "complex" - it's a pretty simple SQL query actually.

Answer (score 2):

Whatever algorithm you come up with for the database as-it-is is likely to be slow for this kind of data. You do need an efficient text-based search, lucene-based solutions like solr or elasticsearch will do nicely here. It would be the best option here, though finding a match against a 3rd token in a string is not something I know how to build without further googling.

You can also write a job in your db which will let you build a reverse map, string->id. like this:

```
rownum, id, text            
1       1   the cat is black
2       3   nice cat
```

to

```
key,    rownum, id
1_the   1       1
2_cat   1       1
3_is    1       1
4_black 1       1
1_nice  2       3
2_cat   2       3
```

*If you can order by ID you don't need rownum. You should also call the column something else instead of rownum, I leave it like that for clarity*

Now you can search for 1st ID where the word `cat` is a 2nd word like this by searching

```
SELECT ID WHERE ROWNUM=1 AND key='3_CAT'
```

Provided you created an (`id`, `key`) or (`key`, `id`) index, your searches should be pretty quick.

If you can fit all that data into memory, then you can use a simple `Map<MyKey, Long>` to do your search. `MyKey` would be, more or less `Pair<Long,String>` with proper equals and hashCode (and/or Comparable, if you use TreeMap) implementations.

Answer (score 2):

(Thanks to Daniel Grosskopf for pointing out that I initially misinterpreted the question.)

This query will give you what you want with just SQL. It gets a running total of the counts of the occurrences of a word (e.g. 'cat') within the text, and then it returns the first row that hits the threshold that you want (e.g. 3).

```
SELECT id, text
  FROM (SELECT entries.*,
               SUM((SELECT COUNT(*)
                      FROM regexp_split_to_table(text, E'\\s+') AS words(word)
                     WHERE word = 'cat')) OVER (ORDER BY id) AS running_count
          FROM entries) AS entries_with_running_count
 WHERE running_count >= 3
 LIMIT 1
```

See it in action in [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!15/d6b1d/22/0)

Comment: I recommend avoiding premature optimization. The solution I provided is about as simple as you could make it. If it doesn't solve the problem within reasonable performance parameters, then try a more complicated solution.

Comment: He wants to get the row with the third time cat occurs *across* rows, this will only check a single row at a time until "text" for a single row contains 3 occurrences of 'cat'.

Comment: @DanielGrosskopf, you're wrong about what my query does, but you're right about my misinterpretation of the question. Thanks for clarifying.

Answer (score 1):

> How would you handle this in an efficient way? Is there any trick you
>   can do directly in the database?

You are not specifying what other restrictions/requirements you may have or what is your definition of

> a big number of matches.

As a general answer I would say that doing string manipulation in the database is **not** an efficient approach.
It is too slow and imposes much work on your DB which is usually a shared resource.
IMO you should do this programmatically.
A way to do this could be to keep metadata in another table i.e. indexes of rows that contain the text cat and where in the sentence.
You can query this meta-table in order to figure the rows to query from your main table.
This extra table is more efficient than searching your defined table because queries with `LIKE` on suffixes can not use an index and you will end up with serial scans which would result in very slow performance

Comment: a big number of matches is 1 million, there are no other restriction but you can use any database or technology I guess to make this efficient; usually when we talk about an algorithm we think of generic solution so cat is just an example, this also has to work for "dog" or any other word, so using a secondary table to keep all the words will not work

Comment: @danip: You still not provide enough information because 1 million strings does not seem too much unless you have some memory restrictions. Anyway, regardless of that I keep my answer as is about efficiency. Doing string processing in the database is definitely not the efficient approach for the reasons I already mention in the answer

Comment: I guess just 1 million string is not more then 100MB but still usually the objects retrieve from database are more complex and mapped by an ORM. I didn't want to involve such variables. Even so, for a backend application to execute such queries multiple times (10k-50k) concurrently will surely deplete the memory at some point. To get more context this is a simple find/find next function in an application that keeps sentences from articles in database rows.

Comment: @danip:I would suggest to check my answer and suggestion

Answer (score 1):

Solution for the Postgres database:

Add a new column to your table:

```
alter table my_table add text_as_array text[];
```

This column will contain the sentence spliced into words:

```
"the cat is black" -> ["the","cat","is","black"]
```

Populate this column with values from current records:

```
update my_table set text_as_array = string_to_array(text,' ');
```

(and don't forget to set it's value to `string_to_array(text,' ')` when inserting new records)

Create a [gin](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.3/static/textsearch-indexes.html) index on it:

```
create index my_table_text_as_array_index on text_as_array gin(text_as_array);
analyze my_table;
```

Then all you need is run a fast query as simple as this:

```
select *
from   my_table
where  text_as_array @> ARRAY['cat'] 
and    text_as_array[3] = 'cat' -- third word in sentence
order  by id
limit  1 
offset 2  -- second occurrence
```

It took 11ms to search over ~2,400,000 records in tests I did in my machine.

Explain:

```
Limit  (cost=11252.08..11252.08 rows=1 width=104)
  ->  Sort  (cost=11252.07..11252.12 rows=19 width=104)
        Sort Key: id
        ->  Bitmap Heap Scan on my_table  (cost=48.21..11251.83 rows=19 width=104)
              Recheck Cond: (text_as_array @> '{cat}'::text[])
              Filter: (text_as_array[3] = 'cat'::text)
              ->  Bitmap Index Scan on my_table_text_as_array_index  (cost=0.00..48.20 rows=3761 width=0)
                    Index Cond: (text_as_array @> '{cat}'::text[])
```

[image]

Comment: I think you misinterpreted the condition about the third occurrence. The example in the question does not have any third `cat` within an individual sentence, nor is the third word `cat`. Instead, the OP is looking for the third occurrence over all rows.

Comment: Adding another column to the table has two problems: 1. you need to manually deal with UPDATEs. 2. it blows up the table, leading to more block reads to scan through the table. Both problems are eliminated when using an index.

Answer (score 0):

A *"directly in the database"* solution seems preferable from an efficiency standpoint as most types of abstraction layer or loading/processing elsewhere are likely to incur additional overheads.

If the source text can be massaged such that only spaces separate the words  *([as mentioned in the comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33309614/implement-find-find-next-algorithm#comment-54477395) - perhaps by pre-processing to suitably replace all non-alphabetical characters?)*, the following (My)SQL-only solution will work:

```
#############################################################
SET @searchWord = 'cat', # Search word: Must be lower case  #
    @n = 1,              # n where nth match is to be found #
#############################################################
    @matches = 0;        # Initialise local variable

SELECT s.*
FROM sentence s
WHERE id = 
(SELECT subq.id
 FROM
 (SELECT *,
         @matches AS prevMatches,
         (@matches := @matches + LENGTH(`text`) - LENGTH(
                      REPLACE(LOWER(`text`),
                              CONCAT(' ', @searchWord, ' '),
                              CONCAT(@searchWord, ' ')))
          + CASE WHEN LEFT(LOWER(`text`), 4) = CONCAT(@searchWord, ' ') THEN 1 ELSE 0 END
          + CASE WHEN RIGHT(LOWER(`text`), 4) = CONCAT(' ', @searchWord) THEN 1 ELSE 0 END)
     AS matches
  FROM sentence) AS subq
 WHERE subq.prevMatches < @n AND @n <= subq.matches);
```

**Explanation**

All instances of `' cat '` on each line are replaced with a word that is one letter shorter. The difference in length is then calculated to find out the number of instances. Finally, the single possibilities of `'cat '` and `' cat'` appearing a the start and end of the line are respectively catered for. Having done this, a cumulative total of `matches` is maintained for each line. This is bundled up into a subquery from which the *nth* match can be picked by finding the row where the number of cumulative number of matches is no greater than n but the previous total is less than n.

**Further potential improvements**

1. The above could of course be slightly simplified by making the source text lower case *(which seems sensible if it is being pre-processed)* and removing all calls to `LOWER()`.
2. The subquery calculates a cumulative total number of matches. If it is likely that the same search terms will be reused, it might conceivably be possible to cache these results in another table and use triggers to maintain this whenever records are updated, inserted or deleted - however this would greatly add to the complexity and data storage requirements.

Answer (score 0):

I would search for all rows with "cat" but limit the rows by ***n***.  This should give you a reasonably sized subset of your data that is guaranteed to contain the row you are looking for.  The SQL would look similar to this:

```
select id, text
  from your_table
 where text ~* 'cat'
  order by id
 limit 3 --nth time cat appears
```

I would then implement your solution as a pl/pgsql function to get the id that contains the nth occurrence of your word:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION your_schema.row_with_nth_occurrence(character varying, integer)
  RETURNS integer AS
$BODY$
Declare
  arg_search_word ALIAS FOR $1;
  arg_occurrence ALIAS FOR $2;

  v_sql         text;
  v_sql2        text;
  v_count       integer;
  v_count_total integer;
  v_record      your_table%ROWTYPE;

BEGIN

v_sql := 'select id, text
            from your_table
           where text ~* ' || arg_search_word || '
           order by id
           limit ' || arg_occurrence || ';';

v_count := 0;
v_count_total  := 0;
FOR v_record IN v_sql LOOP
  v_sql2 := 'SELECT count(*)
               FROM regexp_split_to_table('||v_record.text||', E'\\s+') a
              WHERE a = '|| arg_search_word ||';';
  EXECUTE v_sql2 INTO v_count;
  v_count_total := v_count_total + v_count;
  IF v_count_total >= arg_occurrence THEN
    RETURN v_record.id;
  END IF;
END LOOP;

RAISE EXCEPTION '% does not occur % times in the database.', arg_search_word, arg_occurrence;
END;
```

All this function does is loop through the subset of rows potentially containing the desired word, counts the number of times it occurs in each row, and then returns the Id when it finds the row with the nth occurrence of the word.

Answer (score 0):

Solution one:
Keep the rows in memory but centralized. All clients loop over the same list. Probably fast enough en reasonably memory friendly.

Solution two:
Use the streaming ResultSet technique from the JDBC driver; e.g.

```
     Statement select = connection.createStatement(ResultSet.TYPE_FORWARD_ONLY, ResultSet.CONCUR_READ_ONLY);
     select.setFetchSize(Integer.MIN_VALUE);
     ResultSet result = select.executeQuery(sql);
```

As explained in http://dev.mysql.com/doc/connector-j/en/connector-j-reference-implementation-notes.html, scroll down to Resultset. This should be memory friendly.

Now simply count on the result rows until satisfied and close the result.

Answer (score 0):

I am having trouble understanding your statement:

> eg: "Select the 3rd match for the word cat, that is the number 2
>   entry." Results: the 2nd row from the result where the 3rd word is cat

I will assume that you mean, you want to search for entries where the 3rd word of the text is "cat", and from those entries you want to second entry.

Since you mentioned that your problem lies with the concurrent access and the speed, you will need to somehow build an index which is optimized for your query. You could use anything for this, database, lucene, etc. My suggestion would be to build the index in-memory. Just think of it as a warm up for your service before it could start serving request.

In your case, you would want some kind of map with the word and word position as the key. This key will then map to a list of row numbers which is matching the key. So in the end, you will just have to do a lookup twice, first is to get a list of row numbers where it matches, then the row number which you want. So the performance you will need in the end will be a simple map lookup + array list lookup (constant).

I've provided a very simple example below. It's untested code, but it should roughly give you an idea.

You could also save the index into a file after it's been built if you want. After you have been the index and load them into memory, this will be very very fast.

```
// text entry from the DB
public class TextEntry {
    private int rowNb;
    private String text;
    // getters & setters
}

// your index class
public class Index {
    private Map<Key, List<Integer>> indexMap;
    // getters and setters

    public static class Key {
        private int wordPosition;
        private String word;
        // getters and setters
    }
}

// your searcher class
public class Searcher {

    private static Index index = null;
    private static List<TextEntry> allTextEntries = null;


    public static init() {
        // init all data with some synchronization check

        // synchronization check whether index has been built

        allTextEntries.forEach(entry -> {
          // split the words, and build the index based on the word position and the word
          String[] words = entry.split(" ");
          for (int i = 0; i < words.length; i++) {
              Index.Key key = new Index.Key(i + 1, words[i]);
              int rowNumber = entry.getRowNb();
              // if the key is already there, just add the row number if it's not the last one
              if (indexMap.contains(key)) {
                  List entryMatch = indexMap.get(key);
                  if (entryMatch.get(entryMatch.size() - 1) !== rowNumber) {
                    entryMatch.add(rowNumber);
                  }
              } else {
                  // if key is not there, add a new one
                  List entryMatch = new ArrayList<Integer>()
                  entryMatch.add(rowNumber);
                  indexMap.put(key, entryMatch);
              }
          }
        });
    }

    public static TextEntry search(String word, int wordPosition, int resultNb) {
        // call init if not yet called, do some check

        int rowNb = index.getIndexMap().get(new Index.Key(word, wordPosition)).get(resultNb - 1);
        return allTextEntries.get(rowNb);
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

In mysql
We need one function where we can count number of occurence of given substring in a field.

Create the Function (This function will count occurence of substring in given column)

```
 CREATE FUNCTION substrCount(
         x varchar(255), delim varchar(12)) returns int
    return (length(x)-length(REPLACE(x,delim, '')))/length(delim);
```

This function should be able to find how many times 'cat' was present in text. 
Please bear with me for syntax of code as it may not be fully functional(correct as required).

I will break this problem into 3 parts and we can do with the help of stored procedure.

1. Select all the rows containing the string 'cat' (or any other input).This should select maximum of n rows( n= no of occurences), so we will use limit in our query.
2. With cursor, iterate matched rows in while roop.
3. Increment occurence matches per row in count variable and exit once number of matches found.(Should be able to find match within 1 to n loops)

create stored procedure. 
Assuming proper index ,this should be fast.

```
DELIMITER $$

CREATE PROCEDURE find_match(INOUT string_to_match varchar(100),
 INOUT occurence_count INTEGER,OUT match_field varchar(100))
BEGIN

 DECLARE v_count INTEGER DEFAULT 0;
 DECLARE v_text varchar(100) DEFAULT "";

 -- declare cursor and select by the order you want.
 DEClARE matcher_cursor CURSOR FOR 
 SELECT textField FROM myTable 
        where textField like string_to_match 
              order by id 
              LIMIT 0, occurence_count;

 -- declare NOT FOUND handler
 DECLARE CONTINUE HANDLER 
        FOR NOT FOUND SET v_finished = -1;

 OPEN matcher_cursor;

 get_matching_occurence: LOOP

 FETCH matcher_cursor INTO v_text;

 IF v_count = -1 THEN 
 LEAVE get_matching_occurence;
 END IF;

 -- use substring count function 
 v_count:= v_count + substrCount(v_text,string_to_match));

-- if count is equal to greater than occurenece that means matching row is found.
IF (v_count>= occurence_count) THEN

 SET match_field = v_text;
 v_count:=-1;

END IF;

 END LOOP get_matching_occurence;

 CLOSE _

END$$

DELIMITER ;
```

Answer (score 0):

I would simply count the number of words in each line and then do a cumulative sum.  I'm not sure what the most efficient way is to count words, but a difference of lengths might win:

```
select t.*
from (select t.*, sum(cnt) over (order by id) as cumecnt
      from (select t.*,
                   (length(' ' || str || ' ') - length(replace(' ' || str || ' '), ' cat ', '')) / length(' cat ') as cnt
            from t
           ) t
      where num > 0
     ) t
where cumecnt >= 3 and cumecnt - cnt <= 3;
```

You would simply replace "3" and "cat" with the appropriate strings.

This method requires scanning the strings a handful of times in each row (once for each of the lengths and once for the replace).  My guess is that this is faster than various array operations, regular expressions, or text.  If you have more complicated definitions of what a word is, then you probably need to use regular expression replace:

Doing the work in the database is usually a big win.  However, if you are looking for the 6th match out of one million rows, it might be faster to read back the values from the subquery and do the accumulation in the application.  I don't think there is a way to short-circuit the database calculation to stop just on the "6th" row.

Comment: As far as I can see, this solution doesn't handle "cat" as the first or last word of the text.

Comment: There are still problems with edge cases like "cat cat".

Answer (score 0):

I tested this on a table with 1.2 million rows and it returns data in less than a second. I am using a split function (which is a modified form of Jeff Modem's splitter function) from here: 'http://sqlperformance.com/2012/08/t-sql-queries/splitting-strings-follow-up'.`

```
-- Step 1. Create table
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO
SET ANSI_PADDING ON
GO
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Sentence](
    [id] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [Text][varchar](250) NULL,
CONSTRAINT [PK_Sentence] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
    (
    [id] ASC
    )WITH (PAD_INDEX  = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE  = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS  = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS  = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
    ) ON [PRIMARY]

GO
SET ANSI_PADDING OFF
GO
```

Step 2. Create a split function

```
CREATE FUNCTION [dbo].[SplitSentence]
(
   @CSVString NVARCHAR(MAX),
   @Delimiter NVARCHAR(255)
)
RETURNS TABLE
WITH SCHEMABINDING AS
RETURN
  WITH E1(N)        AS ( SELECT 1 UNION ALL SELECT 1 UNION ALL SELECT 1 UNION ALL SELECT 1 
                     UNION ALL SELECT 1 UNION ALL SELECT 1 UNION ALL SELECT 1 
                     UNION ALL SELECT 1 UNION ALL SELECT 1 UNION ALL SELECT 1),
   E2(N)        AS (SELECT 1 FROM E1 a, E1 b),
   cteTally(N)  AS (SELECT 0 
                    UNION ALL 
                    SELECT TOP (DATALENGTH(ISNULL(@CSVString,1))) ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY (SELECT NULL)) FROM E2),
   cteStart(N1) AS (SELECT t.N+1 
                    FROM cteTally t
                     WHERE (SUBSTRING(@CSVString,t.N,1) = @Delimiter OR t.N = 0))
  SELECT Word = SUBSTRING(@CSVString, s.N1, ISNULL(NULLIF(CHARINDEX(@Delimiter,@CSVString,s.N1),0)-s.N1,50))
  FROM cteStart s;
```

Step 3. Create a sql script to return the required data

```
DECLARE @n int = 3
DECLARE @Word varchar(50) = 'cat'
;WITH myData AS 
(SELECT TOP (@n)
    id
    ,[Text]
    ,sp.word
    ,ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY Id) RowNo
FROM 
    Sentence 
CROSS APPLY (SELECT * FROM SplitSentence(Sentence.[Text],' ')) sp
WHERE Word = @Word)
SELECT 
    * 
FROM 
    myData 
WHERE 
    RowNo = @n
```

Assumptions:

```
 1. The sentence has a max length of 250 characters. If needed this can be modified in the create table statement.
 2. The sentence will not have more than a 100 words. If more than 100 words are needed, the split function will have to be modified.
 3. Any word in the sentence has a max length of 50 characters.
```

SQL Fiddle demo here: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/0a1d0/1

```
Notes: 
I am aware that the original requirement is for MySQL/pgsql, 
but I have limited knowledge of these and therefore my solution has been created/tested in MSSQL.
```